# Differences and similarities between פרס and פרש

Tags: words, language, yirmiyahu--book-of, lamentations-eicha

I wondered what the differences and similarities of the roots פרס and פרש are?
I noticed that both roots are used in Jeremiah 16:7 and Lamentations 4:4 for the 'deviding or sharing' of bread.

Any clues why in one verse פרס is used and in another פרש ?
(p.s. it seems to me that both verbs are related, is that correct?).

Comment: Check out R Meir Zikal's article in _Yerushaseinu_ Vol. 6 about the end of the Hashkivenu blessing on Friday night.

Comment: Doesn't פרס mean "to spread out"?